# working with delays on arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I have just started playing with arduino.  I am a little curious as to the `delay(1000)` method.  Below is a very simple project, where i was just trying to print int i at the default loop rate, yet have the led on port 13

```
int led = 13;
int i =0;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello");  

}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  i++;
  Serial.println(i);  // wait for a second
  blink(1000); 

}

void blink(int duration){
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(duration);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(duration); 

}
```

I moved the actual blink code to its own method in hopes that the delay was actually acting like a pause for the method its in, but it slows down my print as well.

Is there a way to have the lights blink at one rate with out effecting the rate of the loop?

Comment: Yes, use an interrupt. There's [an example on the Arduino playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Interrupts)

Comment: I am looking at interupts here but could you demonstrate